# inserting integer digits as elements

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, object

### Sudoku with Java Arrays

I am building a 9x9 2D array and trying to fill it by inputting a random 9 digits integer for each row. I want to insert each digit of that number as an element along the rows [0][0-8],[1][0-8]... I tried to convert the integer into a string and insert each character but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
System.out.println("Please insert 9 lines of 9 digits (1-9)");

int Choise = scan.nextInt();
char c =(char)Choise;
int soduko[][] = new int[9][9];

for (int i = 0; i< soduko.length; i++){
    for(int j =0; j< soduko.length; j++){
        soduko[i][j]=c;
    }
}
```

i have tried another way that still uses the number as an int, by taking the remainder of that number to the last cell in the row, and dividing the number by 10 each time in the loop. although its not working when i try to divide by 10 to get the next remainder.

```
System.out.println("Please insert 9 lines of 9 digits (1-9)");
Choise = scan.nextInt();

for (int i =0; i <= soduko.length -1; i++){
        for(int j = soduko.length -1; j > 0; j--){
                int ChoiseDigit = Choise % 10;
                soduko[0][j] = ChoiseDigit;
                Choise = (int)(Choise / 10);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Instead of thinking in terms of assigning each digit of 9-digit random number to a cell of a row, it might be easier to think in term of assigning a random one-digit number to each cell of the 2D grid.

Answer (score 0):

Building on your string conversion idea, you might benefit from using the split() method, which splits up a string based on a string you pass as an argument, and then returns an array of the split-up strings. So when you do split(""), the string is split up into single characters. Then you can parseInt to turn each string into an int. I would also recommend putting the scanner input in the loop, to make sure the user has to input a string 9 times.

```
System.out.println("Please insert 9 lines of 9 digits (1-9)");
    int soduko[][] = new int[9][9];
    for (int i = 0; i< soduko.length; i++){
        //reading a string of input 9 times and splitting them by "" into 1-character strings
        String Choise[] = scan.nextLine().split("");
        for(int j =0; j< soduko[i].length; j++){
            //Integer.parseInt converts each string to an int so we can save it to the 2d array
            soduko[i][j]= Integer.parseInt(Choise[j]);
        }
    }
```